# How to add warning message on a wicket Form

Tags: wicket

I am adding  a warning message using form.warn method but the warning message is not getting displayed. how do you add warning message on a wicket form

```
public class FormPanel extends BreadCrumbPanel {

public FormPanel(String id, IBreadCrumbModel breadCrumbModel)
{
    super(id, breadCrumbModel);
    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form");
    form.add(new SaveButton("save"));
    form.add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));


}

private class SaveButton extends Button {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public SaveButton(String id) {
            super(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
             validate(getForm());
          }
}
validate(Form<?> form){
   if(some logic)
     form.warn(“message”);
}
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You better move your validation logic to `IValidator#validate()` or `IFormValidator#validate()`.

Currently you call it in `Button#onSubmit()`. That means Wicket believes everything is valid in your form fields and calls the last step - `onSubmit()`. Usually after `onSubmit()` you either render a completely different page or a new instance of the current page. In both cases the current page instance is lost together with its Form and its feedback messages.

If `IValidator#validate()` fails then Wicket will call `onError()` instead and re-render the **current** page instance.